# How to properly add \section*{} to PDF bookmarks?

Tags: bookmarks

In this MWE, I don't understand why the first PDF bookmark links to the first `\section*`, while the second bookmark doesn't.

What have I missed?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=false,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \pdfbookmark[section]{1st section}{}
    \section*{Section 1}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \pdfbookmark[section]{2nd section}{}
    \section*{Section 2}

\end{document}
```

### Update #1

For Heiko's answer, I know it is less than issue, but I am curious to understand why the first bookmark points exactly to the section title

[image]

while the second doesn't

[image]

### Update #2

When I tried to understand the effect of options `bold` or `color`, I found nothing bold nor red.

What do I misunderstand about these options?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\sectionbookmark}[1][]{%
  \bookmark[%
    level=section,%
    dest=\@currentHref,%
    #1%
  ]%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \section*{Section 2}
    \sectionbookmark[bold,color=red]{2nd section}
    \lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The last mandatory argument of `\pdfbookmark` must be a *unique* name. It is used for the internally created anchor:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \pdfbookmark[section]{1st section}{sec1}
    \section*{Section 1}
    \lipsum[1-3]
    \pdfbookmark[section]{2nd section}{sec2}
    \section*{Section 2}

\end{document}
```

The problem with the previous approach is, that `\pdfbookmark` creates a new anchor and this occurs *before* the `\section*` command. Thus it happens, that the first anchor is closer at the `\section*` command, because at the place at the top of the page. The second `\section*` adds additional space. Even a page break can occur.

Package `bookmark` is already loaded, thus it can be used to call `\bookmark` instead. This command allows the setting of an existing destination. The last argument of `\pdfbookmark` for unique anchor names is no longer necessary. Package `hyperref` stores the last destination name in `\@currentHref`.

Macro `\sectionbookmark` uses `\bookmark` with this destination name and uses the section level as default. The example also shows, how it can be used for other section levels. Also additional options can be given, like font options (`bold`, `italic`) or option `color`.

Since the last destination name is used, `\sectionbookmark` must be given 
right after the `\section*` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hidelinks,bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\sectionbookmark}[1][]{%
  \bookmark[%
    level=section,%
    dest=\@currentHref,%
    #1%
  ]%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \section*{Section 1}
    \sectionbookmark{1st section}
    \lipsum[1-3]

    \section*{Section 2}
    \sectionbookmark[bold]{2nd section}

    \subsection*{Subsection}
    \sectionbookmark[level=subsection]{subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I would be grateful if you could consider my question update.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Answer updated.

Comment: I really appreciate your elite explanation. I have something I don't understand, why when I load `xcolor` package and use `\sectionbookmark[bold,color=red]{2nd section}` I found nothing bold nor red? Why are those options not doing anything? You may look at my second update.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou You have to use a PDF viewer, which support this features, e.g. Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: Ohh that is my bad, SumatraPDF fooled me. Many thanks for considering my naïve inquiries.